# How to display two coefficients vertically in one equation?

Tags: beamer, equations

I'm working on a beamer presentation where I would like to display the regression specification as below:

[image: regression_sample]

Any advice on how to achieve it?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I'd like it to write it in Beamer.  A solution in the comment (deleted now?) worked for me, which was " Define \newcommand{\coefs}[2]{\genfrac{}{}{0pt}{}{#1}{#2}} and then use \coefs{c_1}{c_2}"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry for deleting the comment. After posting it I thought you wanted something else, so I removed it.

What I suggested was using `amsmath`'s `\genfrac` command to create a "general fraction". The `\genfrac` command has 6 arguments:

```
\genfrac{left-delim}{right-delim}{thickness}{mathstyle}{numerator}{denominator}
```

For your case, both `delim`s are empty. The `delims` are used, for example, for the `\binom` command.

You also don't want a fraction rule between the items, so `thickness` is `0pt`.

The `mathstyle` is an integer in the range 0--3 to choose between `\displaystyle`, `\textstyle`, `\scriptstyle`, and `\scriptscriptstyle`, respectively. If left empty the style is taken from the current context.

Finally, `numerator` and `denominator` are what you want them to be.

For convenience you can define, for example:

```
\newcommand{\coefs}[2]{\genfrac{}{}{0pt}{}{#1}{#2}}
```

and then use as:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand{\coefs}[2]{\genfrac{}{}{0pt}{}{#1}{#2}}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\[
y = a + \!\coefs{c_1}{c_2} x + \epsilon
\]
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

(I also added a negative space before the coefficients to make it look more balanced).

[image]

Answer (score 9):

Something like this? (Note that I wouldn't make the terms `c_1` and `c_2` as microscopically small as they appear in the screenshot you posted.)

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\[
y = a + \begin{matrix} c_1 \\ c_2 \end{matrix} x + \epsilon
\]
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\[
y = a + {}_{c_1^{}}^{c_2^{}} x + \epsilon
\]
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! I've taken the liberty of editing your posting to (a) make it fully compilable and (b) add a screenshot. Feel free to revert if you disagree with my changes; alternatively, consider adding a couple of sentences to express your main coding idea in words. (Code-only answers tend to be less helpful and useful.)

Answer (score 0):

How about?

```
\[
y=a+_{c_2}^{c_1}x+\epsilon
\]
```

Comment: Please explain if (and how) this answer differs meaningfully from [the one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/439156/5001) provided by @AndyRufasto.